# dismiss keyboard when the textfield does not have IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, iboutlet

How can I dismiss the keyboard in iOS when the textfield does not have an IBOutlet to the view controller? My case is a UITableView with dynamic prototype cells. One of those cells contains a UITextField, however I cannot add an IBOutlet because outlets are not allowed in repeating content.

So how can I achieve to dismiss the keyboard when textfield does not have outlet?

Answer (score 1):

Add any one method  in your **ViewController.m** file :

**Choice -1**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

**Choice -2**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resignFieds)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

- (void)resignFieds {

   //choice - 1 , check the all subviews and resign textfield
    for (UIView * txt in self.view.subviews){
    if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [txt isFirstResponder]) {
        [txt resignFirstResponder];
    }
   else
  {
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
  }

}
  //choice 2 , no need to check any subviews ,
   [self.view endEditing:YES];

 Note : use any one choice 

}
```

Comment: tanxs a lot my dear friend

Comment: Choice 2 cannot be used, I don't have outlet (yourtextField).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
[view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: I actually found this line, searching in older SO posts, however  I don't know where to add that line. I added an IBAction to catch the end editing event and then [self.view endEditing:YES] but the code never reached there

Comment: You mean you want to catch the end editing event ? Mean how to make end editing? Maybe add a gesture as @krushnsinh answer can help you

Comment: What happens when I need to click to something else after the [view endEditing:]? Everytime I click on a row (didSelectIndex..) the segue is not performed.

Answer (score 0):

try these..

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(taped:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];


-(void)taped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
   [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

OR

you can do these also..

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   if (![[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) 
   {
       [self.view endEditing:YES];
   }
   [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

i hope it helps..

Comment: I prefer the touchesBegan. But in order to use it do I need something extra? Do I need the UITaoGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

In Swift:-

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(Selector("resignFirstResponder"), to: nil, from: nil, forEvent: nil)
```

In Objective-C:-

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
```

Explanation:-

We can send an action to the first responder by calling sendAction:to:from:forEvent on the UIApplication singleton and passing nil as the target and in your case your first responder is your textfield.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you’ve created custom dynamic prototype cell which have UITextField in it.

No need to have IBOutlet of UITextField in your ViewController class where you have added UITableView.

Create Custom TableViewCell Class, then create IBOutlet of UITextField in Custom TableViewCell Class.

```
@interface SimpleTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *simpleTxtField;

@end
```

Set TableViewCell Class to Custom TableViewCell class say “SimpleTableViewCell”. by selecting TableViewCell and selecting Identity Inspector icon in Right side pane in Xcode.

in your ViewController class confirm to UITextField Delegate. like this.

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *simpleTableView;

@end
```

implement UITextField delegate Method.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

then in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView Datasource set your Custom TableViewCell’s (SimpleTableViewCell) TextField Delegate to self.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SimpleTableViewCell *cell = [self.simpleTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"simpleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.simpleTxtField.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

and whenever you select TextField of Cell a Keyboard will display and when you click return key a TextField Delegate method will get call and Keyboard will get dismiss.
Hope this will help.